# Raspberry Pi - Press for on / Press for off switch

Tags: gpio, python, rpi.gpio, switches

I've begun tinkering with using electronics and am also new to using Python.
I was wondering if someone could help me please?

What I'm trying to achieve is to use an on/off switch to run a motor - the first press of the switch turns the motor on and keeps it running, then the second press turns the motor off.

I have tried the below code but all it does is run the motor if I hold the switch on, and then turns off when I let go of the switch.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(20, GPIO.OUT) # LED
GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.OUT) # Motor
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.IN,  pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP) # Switch Button

LED = 20
Motor = 22
Switch = 24

p = GPIO.PWM(22,100)
p.start(0)

try:
    while True:
            if GPIO.input(Switch) == False:
                    p.ChangeDutyCycle(100)
                    GPIO.output(Motor, True)
                    GPIO.output(LED, True)

            if GPIO.input(Switch) == True:
                    p.ChangeDutyCycle(100)
                    GPIO.output(Motor, False)
                    GPIO.output(LED, False)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "CTRL-C pressed.  Program exiting...Exited"
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

I'm away from home at the moment but I've tried to knock up a quick circuit diagram. There is a resistor and diode inline with the transistor but the general gist is there.

[image: Circuit diagram]

Comment: Perhaps you could add a photo of your circuit?

Answer (score 0):

This script will toggle the motor on and off.

It uses my pigpio but you can do the same with RPi.GPIO.

The pigpio daemon needs to be running (`sudo pigpiod`).

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pigpio
import time

LED = 20
Motor = 22
Switch = 24

Motor_On = False

def callback(gpio, level, tick):
   # Toggle motor on and off.
   global Motor_On
   Motor_On = not Motor_On
   pi.write(LED, Motor_On)
   if Motor_On:
      pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(Motor, 200) # 0 is off, 255 is fully on.
   else:
      pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(Motor, 0) # 0 is off, 255 is fully on.

pi = pigpio.pi()
if not pi.connected:
   exit()

pi.set_mode(LED, pigpio.OUTPUT)

pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(Motor, 0) # 0 is off, 255 is fully on.

pi.set_mode(Switch, pigpio.INPUT)
pi.set_pull_up_down(Switch, pigpio.PUD_UP)

cb = pi.callback(Switch, pigpio.FALLING_EDGE, callback)

try:
   while True:
      time.sleep(1.0)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("\nCTRL-C pressed.  Program exiting...Exited")

cb.cancel()
pi.set_mode(LED, pigpio.INPUT)
pi.set_mode(Motor, pigpio.INPUT)
pi.stop()
```

Comment: Hi Joan, thank you for your reply - much appreciated. i have tried this code but it is only running the motor for a split second after pressing the switch instead of keeping it on constantly.

Comment: The first button press  starts PWM on the motor GPIO.  The second button press stops PWM.  Does your circuit work with PWM?  You can view the GPIO outputs with [piscope](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html).

Comment: The circuit currently does and i was hoping to go more into depth with it once this part is figured out. I will give piscope a go, thank you for the recommendation

Comment: @addyc1986 As a quick test you could change the 200 to 255 above. That would be the equivalent of your current code which is full on or full off.

Comment: Hi Joan, i think i may have tried that last night, will confirm later on